# Using Rules to perform Node Export

Tags: rules, importing-exporting

I would like to be able to use Rules to have the Node Export module create an XML file whenever a certain type of node has been updated. I have set up a Content Type with a display and an edit screen. The edit screen includes a Save button. I have also set up a Node Export which has successfully created an XML file with data from the node. It runs via a Node Export tab on the display screen of the node. What I would like to do is have the Node Export to XML occur whenever the Save Button is clicked, right after the update of the data is done. I began to create a Rule for this. For the Event, I chose "After updating existing content". However, under "Actions" I was not able to find any reference to Node Export. Has anyone been able to do this or can anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Node Export tab points to a link, so I was able to get this working by setting 'Actions' to 'Page redirect', and pointing it to the page that the Node Export tab points to, a page within the node called 'node_export', e.g. '../node/1602/node_export', where '1602' is the node id (nid). So I entered 'node/[node:nid]/node_export' as the Value of the URL to which it is to be redirected. I also left 'Force redirect' checked. Now when I click the Save button it performs the node export to XML after updating.

Comment: Thxs for this solution. I will use it. Do you know the configuration how to export it to a file?